# Bootstrap responsive design not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I believe we don't have to do anything in bootstrap to make it responsive. It is by default.
If the browser size changes the app components adjust accordingly. But somehow the responsive design is not working.

Can anyone please advice Why?

My code is really simple.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Home</title>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The Main wrapper div starts -->
<div class="container">


    <div id="left_layout">
    </div>

 <div id="center_layout"><div class="span6"></div>
 </div>     

<div id="right_layout_one"><</div>      

<div id="right_layout_two"></div>   

<div id="right_layout_three"></div>    
</div>
<!-- Main container div wrapper ends -->
</body>
</html>
```

Custom Css snippet

```
#left_layout{
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position:   absolute;
        top:        50px;   /* margins in pixels */
        bottom:     30px;   /* could also use a percent */
        left:       40px;
        /* right:      10px; */
        min-height: 18px;
        min-width:  250px;
        /* box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        border: 1px; */
        /* -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    }

    /* #center_layout{} */

    #center_layout{
        display: block;
        background: #F8F8F8;
        position:   absolute;
        top:        50px;   /* margins in pixels */
        bottom:     30px;   /* could also use a percent */
        left:       327px;
        right:      430px;
        min-height: 18px;
        min-width:  465px;
        /* box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; */
        /* -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px; */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    }
```

What's the point of downvoting the question. If one does not know one will ask

Comment: Does this error occur on all your webpages where the bootstrap.css has bee imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Try adding these lines at bottom insteed on header tag.

```
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

instead of giving

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.css
```

try to give exact path location and give a try.

====================================

I have found out what the problem is

you are not using the class which is to be used for responsive layout using Bootstrap 3.
you better read the documents of [GRID SYSTEM](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Just try the code below,you take it as an example

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Home</title>
     <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <!-- The Main wrapper div starts -->
     <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="left-side-layout"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
       <div class="right-side-layout"></div>
      </div>     
      </div>
     <!-- Main container div wrapper ends -->
     </body>
     </html>
```

And include this in app.css

```
    .left-side-layout {
       height: 100px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
       box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
       background: #ffffff;
       border: 1px solid #ababab;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
       border-radius: 5px;
     }

    .right-side-layout {
      height: 100px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #F8F8F8;
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #ababab;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
     }
```

Try it.

Note : You shouldn't give fixed width for layout in pixel, if you are looking for a responsive design. instead use

```
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
```

or change the size according to your app. and DO READ THE DOCUMENTATION Before working on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Karthik but there is no problem with the css file path as the other components of bootstrap are working fine. It's just that the responsive feature in not working.

Comment: Thanks Karthik I will try. I really appreciate it.